# how to save time in a variable

Tags: java, session

```
if(session.isNew()) {
        out.println("New Session");
        formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        out.println(formatted + " from inside");
       }
       out.println("Outside time" + formatted);
```

my question -

- HAPPENING - For the first time, the value of formatted is same for inside and outside of the if statement.
  After I refresh the page again, I get null for my formatted value.
- Why is that happening? I wanted to save the current time in formatted variable, so I know what time users have logged into a new session. Any help please...

Comment: You never put it in session.

Comment: I must.. I have to keep track of user loggingin in new session..

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You need `LocalTime` and optionally a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `Session.setAttribute` to store the formatted time using a key in the session and `Session.getAttribute` with the same key to retrieve it.

Comment: @user7723264 Please edit your question post and show the code you had tried.